# $|orbit|$ will be a power of $p$ in case of torsion groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $P$ be a torsion group with every element of order a power of prime $p$, i.e. a torsion $p$-group and $X$ be a finite set. Is it true that if $P$ acts on $X$ via some action then every orbit must have length a power of $p$.?

We cannot apply orbit-stabilizer theorem now as $P$ might not be finite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's true. Let $K$ be the kernel of the action of $G$ on the orbit. Then for $g \in G$, the order of $gK$ in $G/K$ divides the order of $g$ in $G$, so $G/K$ must be a finite $p$-group.

The action of $G$ on the orbit induces an action of $G/K$, and we can apply the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem to that action.